# XDocument treats atributes as Element name

Tags: c#, xml

Im trying to insert data into a specific element of a XML file. When i try to find it with "newDoc.Element("relatorio_unico")" it cant find it.

I used `List<XElement> list = newDoc.Elements().ToList();` to see the list of elements it gets, and it returns this one element, and the name of the element is the whole file.
By trial and error, i found out that what is confusing things is the atributes. If i remove the atributes, it works fine.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<relatorio_unico xmlns="http://www.gep.msess.gov.pt/sguri/ru" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" XML_DATA="3.2.10">
  <header>
    <aplicacao>
      <nome>Aplicação Recolha RU 2021</nome>
      <versao>1.10.40</versao>
      <empresa>GEP</empresa>
    </aplicacao>
  </header>
  <body>
    <entity_data>
      <active_estabs year_ref="2021">
        <estabs annex="RFC" excluded="N"/>
        <estabs annex="GRV" excluded="N"/>
      </active_estabs>
      <entity_config>
        <strikes/>
      </entity_config>
      <entity xmlns="http://www.gep.msess.gov.pt/sguri/sul">
        <entity_id>92698</entity_id>
        <nif/>
        <niss/>
        <name/>
        <address>
          <address/>
          <location/>
          <zipcode/>
          <zipcode_description/>
        </address>
        <dcf tbl="RU_DCF"/>
        <dcf_description/>
        <cae tbl="RU_CAE_5DIG"/>
        <cae_description/>
        <ln tbl="RU_NATJUR"/>
        <ln_description/>
        <phone/>
        <email/>
        <country tbl="RU_CODPAIS"/>
        <country_description/>
        <estabs/>
      </entity>
    </entity_data>
    <anexos>
      <anexo_rfc>
        <nome_entidade>REPSOL</nome_entidade>
        <exist_trabalhadores>S</exist_trabalhadores>
        <dados_rfc>
          <cae_31Dez tbl="RU_CAE_5DIG">1</cae_31Dez>
          <formacoes>
          </formacoes>
          <trabalhadores>
          </trabalhadores>
        </dados_rfc>
      </anexo_rfc>
    </anexos>
  </body>
</relatorio_unico>
```

My goal is to get to `<formacoes>` and `<trabalhadores>` and this is how im doing it:

```
newDoc.Element("relatorio_unico")
    .Element("body")
    .Element("anexos")
    .Element("anexo_rfc")
    .Element("dados_rfc")
    .Element("formacoes")
    .Add(from formacao in _listFormacoes select new XElement(
        "formacao",
        new XElement("area_educacao",
                     new XAttribute("tbl",
                                    lstSettings
                                        .Where(setting => setting.Nome ==
                                                          "area_educacao")
                                        .FirstOrDefault()
                                        .Tabela),
                     formacao.Area_educacao),
        new XElement("modalidade",
                     new XAttribute("tbl", lstSettings
                                               .Where(setting => setting.Nome ==
                                                                 "modalidade")
                                               .FirstOrDefault()
                                               .Tabela),
                     formacao.Modalidade),
        new XElement("duracao_accao", formacao.Duracao_accao),
        new XElement("entidade_formadora",
                     new XAttribute("tbl",
                                    lstSettings
                                        .Where(setting => setting.Nome.Contains(
                                                   "entidade_formadora"))
                                        .FirstOrDefault()
                                        .Tabela),
                     formacao.Entidade_formadora),
        new XElement("qualificacao",
                     new XAttribute("tbl", lstSettings
                                               .Where(setting => setting.Nome ==
                                                                 "qualificacao")
                                               .FirstOrDefault()
                                               .Tabela),
                     formacao.Qualificacao)));
```

Comment: Your doc has a namespace, so you'll need to reference all elements with the namespace.

Comment: How so? isn't "relatorio_unico" the namespace?

Comment: I don't see how that would affect the ability to find the correct element, as this only occurs when a element has attributes